# Displaying records in a SQL Server #temp_table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

what's the select query syntax for displaying the content/records in a #temp_table on a SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

A #temp table works just like any other table in the sense that you can write SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE statements on it.

Examples:

```
UPDATE #someTable SET someColumn=123 WHERE someCriteria=1;

SELECT * FROM #someTable;
```